# Critique my proof of "Let $A, B, C$ be sets. Prove that $(A - B) - C = (A - C) - (B - C)$."

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Critique on correctness, structure, etc.

$(\subseteq)$ Let $x \in (A - B) - C$. Thus, $x \in A \land x \not \in B \land x \not \in C$. $$\text{By conjunction, } x \in A \land x \not \in C$$, so $x \in (A - C)$. $$\text{By addition, } x \not \in B \lor x \in C$$
, so $(x \in A \land x \not \in C) \land (x \not \in B \lor x \in C) \Rightarrow x \in (A- C) - (B - C)$. Thus, $x \in (A - B) - C \Rightarrow x \in (A - C) - (B - C)$, so $(A - B) - C \subseteq (A - C) - (B - C)$.

$(\supseteq)$

Let $x \in (A - C) - (B - C)$. Thus, ($x \in A \land x \not \in C) \land (x \not \in B \lor x \in C)$. $$\text{By conjuction, }x \in A \land x \not \in B \land \not \in C$$, so $x \in (A - B) - C$. Thus, $x \in (A - C) - (B - C) \Rightarrow x \in (A - B) - C$. Thus, $(A - B) - C \subseteq (A - C) - (B - C)$.

$\therefore (A - B) - C = (A - C) - (B - C)$. **Q.E.D**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element chasing proof that $(A\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C) = (A\setminus B)\setminus C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239875/element-chasing-proof-that-a-setminus-c-setminusb-setminus-c-a-setminus). Have you compared your solution with these solutions?

Comment: Nice find, @DietrichBurde !

Comment: @amWhy Oh, thank you...